# Double with comma vs double with period (no TryParse)

Tags: vb.net, console, double, console-application

In my code, I have to validate decimal number, zero and negative number.

If the decimal separator is a comma the code works, but if it's a period the code doesn't work.

If I input 5,3 the output "is not OK"
but if I input 5.3 the output "is OK"

```
Function isInteger(x As Double) As Boolean
        Return x Mod Math.Floor(x) = 0
    End Function 

    Function isAllowed(x As String) As Boolean
         If IsNumeric(x) Then
             If x > 0 Then
                If isInteger(x) Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

Sub Main()

        Dim n1 As String

        n1 = Console.ReadLine()

       if isAllowed(n1) then
          console.writeLine("is OK")
       else
          console.writeLine("is not OK")
       end if

 End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: Read about [**System.Globalization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

Comment: Your code as it stands is doomed to unexpected failures as it uses `IsNumeric` and does not use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable or disable certain features from the Decimal validation, you can use [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) parameter for `Decimal.Parse`. In no case should you validate `.` and `,` equally. They are meant to do separate things, and they are culture dependent.

Trust me, you don't want to reinvent/rewrite how `Decimal.Parse` works. I've seen this code, I've also seen code that mimics `Date.Parse`, but in neither case the author knew much about globalization, so it was two pages of code, accounted for only 50% of the possible inputs, and US-culture specific. Please do us a favor and start using native .NET functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following code. It takes a string as input and evaluates it to a number (double). Hope it helps you out.

```
Public Function ExtractNumber(EenStr As String) As Double
    Dim NumberFound As Double = 0
    If Not IsNothing(EenStr) Then
        Dim Seq As Integer = EenStr.Length
        Dim _10power As Integer = 0
        Dim digits As String = "0123456789.,-"
        While Seq > 0
            If InStr(digits, EenStr(Seq - 1)) > 0 Then
                Dim substring As String = EenStr(Seq - 1)
                If substring = "." Or substring = "," Then
                    NumberFound = NumberFound / (10 ^ _10power)
                    _10power = 0
                Else
                    If substring = "-" Then
                        NumberFound = -NumberFound
                    Else
                        If NumberFound < 0 Then
                            NumberFound -= CInt(substring) * 10 ^ _10power
                        Else
                            NumberFound += CInt(substring) * 10 ^ _10power
                        End If
                    End If
                    _10power += 1
                End If
            End If
            Seq -= 1
        End While
    End If
    ExtractNumber = NumberFound
End Function
```